# Calling a PHP (Fat Free Framework) file from a bash script in Linux is giving me "No Routes Specified" error

Tags: php, linux, bash, fat-free-framework

I am working on a PHP (Fat free framework) project in Linux. The project is running fine when I call it directly from the cli.

```
    > cd /var/www/html/test/proj/source/
    > php index.php controller_name/action_name/parameter1
```

However, I cannot run the project from a bash script. I have created a bash script with following content:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test/proj/source/index.php controller_name/action_name/parameter1
```

I get the following error

> "No routes specified"
>   [/var/www/html/test/proj/source/index.php:LINE_NUMBER] Base->run()

I couldn't find anything about it on https://www.fatfreeframework.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it does not work because the app's root path is a different. Change the working dir with `cd /var/www/html/test/proj/source/` first before calling index.php, because otherwise relative paths within the app are screwed and things like `$f3->config('config.ini')`, where you might have defined the routes, isn't finding the file to load.